# MVC4 Roles methods time out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, roles

Everytime that i need to do a Roles.IsUserInRole or user User.IsInRole i have a timeout:

[image: Role.IsInRole time out]
This is the role class:

[image: Role class]

But doing a GetAllRoles works properly:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reading i realiaze that i was missing this:

```
 [InitializeSimpleMembership]
 public class HomeController : Controller
```

Adding [InitializeSimpleMembership] to the home controller resolves the issue.